# Indent UITableViewCell while editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

how can i indent my **CUSTOM CELL** while editing, resizing or moving labels and images correctly?

I use:

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
  return YES; 
}
```

with no effects.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved animating all components (changing `frame.origin.x`) in this way:

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];

  [cell.CellTitle setFrame:cgrectMake(x+20, y, w, h)];  // +x
  [...]
  [cell.CellAddress setFrame:f2];

  [UIView commitAnimations];

  return YES; 
}
```

On edit / save, animation "indent" controls left or right.

thanks

Comment: While this might work, I would go with jbat100's solution, and avoid writing this code altogether.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you want your cell content to be indented properly when transitioning in/out of edit mode, then you should put all your cell subviews in the UITableViewCell contentView, this is the discussion:

> The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview
>   for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by
>   simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content
>   view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions
>   into and out of editing mode.

If you set your auto-resizing masks correctly then all the resizing should be done right.